# Install .app file in simulator from the command line

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, ios-simulator

How can I install a .app file in the simulator from the command line. Or do I need to install it from a .ipa file and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the app in the simulator you need a third party library like waxsim https://github.com/square/waxsim

You can setup their KIF library for acceptance tests

Then you can do a command line build and run it like this...

waxsim -f "ipad" "${MY_PATH}/MyApp.app" > $OUT_FILE 2>&1

Another option is to use the Frank libraries http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/ These are really easy to install and have a built in way to launch the simulator and run tests!

Comment: Is there no way I can do it without adding any files to Xcode?

Comment: Hey, As far as I was able to find there is no default way to launch the simulator from the command line. It is not built into xcode's command line tools.